# how to appendChild properly

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a dynamic list of music Albums inside a ul with Javascript

```
    var heavyArtillery = new Album("Heavy Artillery","Arkasia","2011");
    var antenna = new Album("Antenna","Sonic Youth","2012");

    albumList = new Array(heavyArtillery,antenna);

    var albumLi;
    var ul = document.getElementById("albumlist");

    for(var i=0; i<albumList.length; i=i+1)
    {

        albumLi  = document.createElement('li');
        albumLi.innerHTML = ""+albumList[i].album;
        //ul.appendChild(albumLi);
        alert(i);


    }
```

If I take the comment from the appendChild line the alert(i) won't even show. Why isn't it working properly? here's the HTML fragment:

```
<div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
    <h3>
        Albums
    </h3>
</div>

<ul id="albumlist">
</ul>
```

Comment: Where in the document are you executing the code? Check the console if you get an error. A possible problem could be that `ul` is `null` because the element doesn't exist at the moment the code runs.

Comment: how are you defining or creating Album? Are you using a prototype?

Comment: Running the code as is throws an error Album is not defined

Comment: That was the problem. I feel ashamed now haha. Thanks Felix :)